# Linq To Objects - Under The Hood Of Joins

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know what are the differences between those two linq statements?

What is faster?

Are they the same?

What is the difference between this statement

```
from c in categories
from p in products
where c.cid == p.pid
select new { c.cname, p.pname };
```

and this statement?

```
from c in categories
join p in products on c.cid equals p.pid
select new { c.cname, p.pname };
```

Thanks in advance guys.

**EDIT: In context of LINQ to Objects**

Comment: In the context of LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL / EF, or something else?

Comment: I assume you mean `p.pid` in the second query, by the way.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes its p.pid in second query. I will edit that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, within LINQ to Objects the difference can be very dramatic.

The first form examines *every* `c` and `p` pair, checks for `c.cid` being equal to `p.pid` and yields matches.

The second form (within `Join`) first creates a hash-based lookup from `pid` to matching `Product` elements. Then it streams the `categories`, and then checks for each category where there are matching `Product` elements in the lookup based on the `c.cid`. This is generally much more efficient as it only needs to look through `products` once and create the hash-based lookup. On the other hand, it has a higher memory footprint. This is all done somewhat lazily of course - it's only when you ask for the first result that anything significant happens.

For more details on the `Join` operation, see my [Edulinq blog post on the topic](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-19-join.aspx).